expo cannot find android emulator automatically
I am developing an app with expo(react-native) in Mac. If I run the emulator on the terminal, iOS (Press i) runs without problems, but Android (Press a) does not run the emulator and an error occurs.
I ran the emulator as below:

npm start
press "i" and "a"
When I press "i" ios emulator has no problem
When I press "a" Android has the error as the screenshot below.


If I manually run the Android emulator and click "a", the app runs on the emulator that ran without any problems.
Actually, I backed up the source code, reset the Mac then set the development environment again, and ran the program. Before I reset the Mac, the emulator ran normally when I pressed "a" on the terminal without running the Android emulator manually.
I'd appreciate it if you could let me know what I should look into.
Thanks.
